# Angular routerLink not working with Electron

Tags: angular, electron, angular-routerlink

I'm facing a issues about using routerLink with Angular with Electron.

```
<a routerLink="/example">Page Example</a>
```

When this link is clicked, I have a blank page with this error in DevTools :

> file:///< path >/dist/example
> failed net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Thing I already try :

- Set `--base-href` to `./` or `/` or empty
- Add `{ useHash: true }` in `RouterModule.forRoot()`
- Changed from `<a routerLink="/example">Page Example</a>` to :

  - `routerLink="#/example"`, or
  - `routerLink="/#/example"` or
  - `routerLink="index.html/example"` or
  - `routerLink="index.html#/example"`

Linked issues : When I use `window.location.reload()`, it give the same problem

Infos :

- Angular version : 9
- Electron version : 13

Comment: Have you tried to use ` RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' }),` ?